# Данные не передаются из Crashlytics в Bigquery

Tags: bigquery

Доброго времени суток.

В Crashlytics создал link на Bigquery, данные передаются из Google Аналитики, но не для моего источника.
Пробовал отвязывать, привязывать link, но безуспешно. В логах только данные по Аналитике.
Создавал новый трансфер, не помогло.
Есть ошибка при попытке совершить трансфер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гугл не помог по данной ошибке.
Так же создается структура таблицы, но в ней нет данных.